# how to generate a subfactory based on condition of a parent attribute

Tags: factory-boy

I have a factory like so:

```py
class PayInFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = PayIn
  
    @factory.lazy_attribute
    def card(self):
        if self.booking_payment and self.booking_payment.payment_type in [bkg_cts.PAYMENT_CARD, bkg_cts.PAYMENT_CARD_2X]:
            factory.SubFactory(
                CardFactory,
                user=self.user,
            )
```

I'm trying to generate a field `card` only if the `booking_payment` field has a `payment_type` value in `[bkg_cts.PAYMENT_CARD, bkg_cts.PAYMENT_CARD_2X]`

The code goes into that statement but card field is empty after generation.

How can I do that properly ?
Is `SubFactory` allowed in `lazy_attribute` ?

I'd like to be able to modify Card field from PayInFactory if possible like so:

```py
>>> PayInFactory(card__user=some_user)
```

`PostGeneration` won't do as I need this `Card` to be available before the call to create. I overrided `_create` and it may use the card if available.

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution lies in [`factory.Maybe`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#factory.Maybe):

```py
class PayInFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.PayIn

    card = factory.Maybe(
        factory.LazyAttribute(
            lambda o: o.booking_payment and o.booking_payment.payment_type in ...
        ),
        factory.SubFactory(
            CardFactory,
            # Fetch 'user' one level up from CardFactory: PayInFactory
            user=factory.SelfAttribute('..user'),
        ),
    )
```

However, I haven't tested whether the extra params get actually passed to the `CardFactory`, nor what happens when `CardFactory` is not called — you'll have to check (and maybe open an issue on the project if you get an unexpected behaviour!).